# how does the method df.column.str.replace(' ','_') in pandas dataframe work?

Tags: python, pandas

I saw the type of column it is pandas.Index. But I don't understand, how can we use pandas.Index.str as str is a different class. I am proficient in Java so,I don't really understand .. how does this work in python? Can anyone please explain in detail. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might be referring to is the `string` module. It has multiple string methods and classes.

However, `pandas.Index` is a class and it has the `str` method as it can be seen from [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.html). This method allows vectorized string functions to be applied to values(index and series) in the dataframe.